# Rails call Javascript in a Model method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to perform a geocode using Google's encoder.

Before saving, the model will call some javascript. I tried using format.js but it doesn't work the same way as it does in the controller.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :update_coordinates

def update_coordinates
  # Call javascript code here
  # Call google encoder on self.location to fetch longitude and latitude.
  # update self.longitude and self.latitude before save.
end
```

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to call JS in the model? With MVC, controllers and views are tightly bound, but the model should be independent. If you explained what you wanted your JS to do, maybe someone can help you find the right solution.

Comment: I initially was using the controller to perform the javascript, but it does not have a before_save callback. That would mean I have to write the method both in #update and #create. I thought it would be easier to perform a javascript call in before_save.

Comment: Your real goal is to DRY your code? Make one method in your controller that performs the desired JS and call it in both update and create. Or you can tie your script to the Submit button (calling it from your locations.js asset file) so it'll run whether you're creating or updating.

Comment: Now i think of it, it makes sense to keep it in the controller. I simply made a shared js partial to render from.